# Advice on storing EXR

Tags: .exr

I've rendered a gigantic numbers of scenes, which results in around 22TB (yes, the process took several month-computation and resources). Apparently, I cannot use the EXRs out-of-the-box so I have to extract the PNGs from them, which costs additionally 8TB. For storage and backup purpose, I'd like to store and save the EXRs somewhere (you don't really want to throw away a-year-worth effort), but 22TB is a bit too much for me. I am wondering if there's any good way to reduce the size of them, at least to 75% or even better 50%. The EXRs are already made with compression enabled, so even xz level 9 doesn't reduce much space of it (the compression ratio is only about .95)

Comment: Full floats could be saved as half floats and maybe you don't need all of the channels and could remove some of them (e.g. z).

Comment: You could look into tape backup. Sounds like a perfect situation for it. It is not like you are going to be accessing it frequently.

Comment: @Leander just to make clear, EXRs should contain all information and passes from the rendering (because I happen to need them all) but I've extracted the most uses and necessary out. The question now is if there's an efficiently way to store them as backup or archive purpose

Comment: @MartinZ can you elaborate the answer a little more? Currently I am using tar + xz level 9 but only achieved 95% compression ratio. Maybe it's due to the fact that EXRs are already saved in compressed state. Are you aware  of any heavy algorithm that can  achieve better that XZ (in exchange for memory usage and speed...)

Comment: Then this question is not really about the usage of Blender? Maybe it is better suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You could be right, I'm not so sure as well, although my problem arisen from Blender rendering and EXR format, it's technically not a Blender problem. Perhaps somebody has the same storage problem while working with Blender?

Comment: I was talking about physical storage. It seems it might be in your interest to consider cheaper physical storage solutions. I do not have much experience with it but magnetic tape is still used for storage and backup. I think it might be cheaper than hard drives - I mean we are talking about 30TB... It might be worth looking into it if you don't want to delete the EXRs. I just keep uncompressed post processing end result in 16 bits so I can still edit it if needed and delete the EXRs if I use them. I store project files anyway so they can be re-rendered in the unlikely case I would need  them.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's more feasible than HDD then.